# Grails: command not found with Travis-CI

Tags: grails, travis-ci, grails-3.0.9

I want to use [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/) with my Grails 3.0.9 app. For this I created a `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: groovy

jdk:
  - oraclejdk7

before_install:
 - curl -s get.sdkman.io | bash
 - source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
 - sdk install grails 3.0.9
 - sdk default grails 3.0.9

script: grails test-app --stacktrace
```

When the Travis-CI service wants to build my application, it ends up with this error:

```
$ export GRAILS_HOME=/home/travis/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.9/
$ export PATH=$PATH:$GRAILS_HOME/bin
$ ./gradlew assemble
...
(downloading a lot of gradle dependencies)
...
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
$ grails test-app
/home/travis/build.sh: line 45: grails: command not found
```

So do I have to install Grails somehow else or is it because of a missing/wrong path variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a working `.travis.yml` [here](https://github.com/jpms2/ResS/blob/master/.travis.yml):

```
language: groovy

jdk:
  - oraclejdk7

before_install:
- curl -s http://get.sdkman.io | bash
- echo sdkman_auto_answer=true > ~/.sdkman/etc/config
- source "/home/travis/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
- sdk install grails 3.0.9

script: grails test-app --stacktrace
```

**Update:**

Use `get.sdkman.io` since `get.gvmtool.net` doesn't work anymore.

Comment: it seems get.gvmtool.net doesn't work anymore, and now is sdkman, do you know what is the required modification for travis to use sdkman?